# mapViewDidLoad method not loaded

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4.3, arcgis

New to objective c, and I am using ArcGIS for the map portion. I have a problem where the method `mapViewDidLoad` is not called/loaded. Here is some part of the code:

.h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<AGSMapViewLayerDelegate, AGSMapViewTouchDelegate, AGSMapViewCalloutDelegate>{
AGSMapView *_mapView;
AppDelegate *appDelegate;
...
}
```

.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.activityView startAnimating];
    self.mapView.touchDelegate = self;
    self.mapView.calloutDelegate = self;
    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    ...
}

- (void)mapViewDidLoad:(AGSMapView *)mapView {

    AGSEnvelope *envelope = [[AGSEnvelope alloc]initWithXmin:29757.610204117
                                                    ymin:40055.0379682464
                                                    xmax:29884.6992302249
                                                    ymax:40236.6028660071
                                        spatialReference:self.mapView.spatialReference];
    [self.mapView zoomToEnvelope:envelope animated:YES];

    self.mapView.callout.width = 195.0f;
    self.mapView.callout.accessoryButtonHidden = YES;

    [self.mapView.gps start];
    [self.mapView centerAtPoint:self.mapView.gps.currentPoint animated:YES];   
    NSLog(@"Location : %@", self.mapView.gps.currentPoint);

    [self.activityView stopAnimating];
    self.activityView.hidden = YES;

}
```

What is wrong with my code why i doesn't load the `mapViewDidLoad` method.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure that you make mapview connected to outlet and make it's delegate =  self that is fileowner in you case

Comment: yup the outlet mapView is already connected to file owner. Every of my outlet is connected to their proper places

Comment: and the delegate of the mapview is also assigned to fileowner double check this step

Comment: the delegate of the map view is not in the outlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that mapviewdelegate is connected by right click on mapview and then assign delegate..
[image]

or add `[self.mapview setDelegate:self];`

in your case "AGSMapView" mapViewDidLoad: method on AGSMapViewLayerDelegate is invoked after the first layer has been added to the map. At this point, the component is fully functional you can find reference to it in 
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgismobile/10.0/apis/iphone/reference/interface_a_g_s_map_view.html

make self.mapview.layerDelegate = self;

Comment: i do not have the delegate in the outlets portion, and i added `[self.mapview setDelegate:self];` it gives me a warning `'AGSMapView' may not respond to 'setDelegate'` and it crash when running, `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AGSMapView setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x90afc00'`

Comment: try [self.mapview setAGSMapViewDelegate:self];

Comment: also for self.mapview.mapViewDelegate = self

Comment: one of them will work for you and fire your mapViewDidLoad method

Comment: `[self.mapview setAGSMapViewDelegate:self];`, warning `Instance method '-setAGSMapViewDelegate' not found(return type defaults to 'id'`
`self.mapview.mapViewDelegate = self`, got an error `Property MapViewDelegate not found on object of type 'AGSMapView *'`

Comment: make self.mapview.AGSMapViewDelegate = (id)self;

Comment: `Property AGSMapViewDelegate not found on object of type 'AGSMapView *'` something is wrong with my codes aww

Comment: check your code and you can find this reference http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgismobile/10.0/apis/iphone/reference/interface_a_g_s_map_view.html

Comment: yup i found out i need this code `self.mapView.layerDelegate = self;` but i remove it due to some error. `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan nan]'` which i can't find where the problem is at

Comment: Really i don't know you have problem in your code debug and see where is the error and your question was to fire mapViewDidLoad not exception.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `self.mapView.delegate = self;` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Got an error if i add this `Property 'delegate' not found on object of type 'AGSMapView *'`